# Matlab exception (MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error) when call function from C#

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, matlab-compiler

I have strange issue when I call matlab function from C# class. The most of time is everything ok but sometimes (1 call from 100 calls, maybe 1000 or one call in day for example - I can measure it in future) i get a strange MWMCR error. Of course the error cause the exception in my C# code. The behavior is same on two computers.

The message from the exception always seems as follows

`... MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error ...
The file
   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\VF\mcrCache9.2\Matlab1\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\work\frm\file_with_called_function.m"
cannot be executed..`

The details from the exception is

`Failed to open file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\VF\mcrCache9.2\Matlab1\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\work\frm\file_with_called_function.m'. Details: 'File stream is closed. The following flags are set: failbit.'`

And mscorelib error

`mscorlib::Void HandleReturnMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)`

(Of course I have the whole call stack but it does not seem very useful.)

As you can see I use MWMCR v 9.2. (MATLAB 9.2, release R2017a) and MWMCR works in user's temp directory. Interesting is when I explore the directory after error the directory is empty. I do not know that is normal behavior.

**And the question. Why MWMCR sometimes can not open the file (evaluate the function)?? The related question is why is (in my case) [failbit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) on the stream setted and why is filestream closed??**

And subquestions. How MWMCR works with user's tmp folder? MWMCR copy the matlab file to the temp directory, works with them and delete them?? Why is directory empty??

Thank You.

Comment: This is most likely due to antivirus. If you have one, configure scanning to ignore mcr cache folder.

Comment: I thought it would be "antivirus problem" but on second machine (not my personal computer with Eset) is not a antivirus. At least not any special antivirus (only default apps from M$ like defender etc). Could it be the problem?

Comment: Couple of observations: a) why does the MCR directory contain files from R2012b, b) what does the surrounding code in c# do ? c) what data are you fetching from the matlab call ?  on a side note, I would highly recommend you to reach out to the official technical support at Mathworks about this issue.

Comment: @PrateekKhandelwal a)I think it is not important but it is something about compiler version - maybe we use the wrong version of them b)C# code only prepare the data, call the matlab function with calculation (from small formula like factorial, for example, to complex calculations like decay of nuclide) and parse the results c)in this case the exception was threw, but generaly the results of calculations from b) - from one number to complex data structures of structures of arrays. (I will be contact official MW support later if I do not resolve the problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is change default cache location using env variable `MCR_CACHE_ROOT` to location under your control (like project directory, user directory, etc).

Explanation.

The runtime is not probably designed to run long time. It uses standard temporary location (tmp directory) for store scripts and can't find it when OS delete it after some time. Additionally runtime uses something like LRU cache what means that some files looking for in memory cache and some in filesystem cache.

When you always use files in memory cache everything is ok even is directory cache is empty. But when you fill memory cache and you want to use new function runtime tries load it from filesystem cache. When is filesystem cache has been deleted the error will occur.

In my case once per months (depends on type of calculations).